# span not appearing inside it's div

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

Using chrome developer, why doesn't the span after the iframe appear inside it's div tag?

```css
.gl-bot2-flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.gl-bot2-left, .gl-bot2-right{
   width:47%;
   }
```

```html
<div class="gl-bot2-flex">
   <div class="gl-bot2-left">
      <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1EhOE6w1_iHeWWpE_Y52YQjVKf3jxXOV6" width="100%" height="100%"><br />
      </iframe>
      <span class="gl-pin">click on pin to see further details of gas leak</span>
   </div>
   <div class="gl-bot2-right">
      <ul>
         <li>The Audit confirmed 292 unrepaired gas leaks in Weston: 66% more than reported by National Grid 12/31/18. 35% of Weston’s leaks are large volume leaks.</li>
         <li>Using the industry standard “leak extent” method, 102 of the leaks measured 2,000 ft2 or more. These large volume leaks are deemed of “Significant Environmental Impact” (G3SEI) according to the latest ruling by the Department of Public Utilities.</li>
         <li>The largest leak in Weston was first recorded by National Grid<br>
in April 1999 and measures 14,400 ft2 – larger than 5 tennis courts.</li>
         <li>Over 320 trees were assessed as either already compromised or at risk due to their location in the leak zone. The cost of removing and replacing a dead tree can be $2-3,000.</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean when you are inspect this with dev-tools that the span with class `gl-pin` is not between the opening `<div class="gl-bot2-left">` and closing `</div>`?

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. It's appearing in the div element for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iframe being at height 100% is pushing the span outside of the div. You can remove the height and see the span will be inside the div area.
You could do a few different things to make the iframe almost full height with the text under it.
This below is an example using a calculated height instead.

```css
.gl-bot2-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.gl-bot2-left,
.gl-bot2-right {
  width: 47%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

iframe {
  border: 0;
  height: calc(100% - 25px);
}
```

```html
<div class="gl-bot2-flex">
  <div class="gl-bot2-left">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1EhOE6w1_iHeWWpE_Y52YQjVKf3jxXOV6" width="100%"><br />
      </iframe>
    <span class="gl-pin">click on pin to see further details of gas leak</span>
  </div>
  <div class="gl-bot2-right">
    <ul>
      <li>The Audit confirmed 292 unrepaired gas leaks in Weston: 66% more than reported by National Grid 12/31/18. 35% of Weston’s leaks are large volume leaks.</li>
      <li>Using the industry standard “leak extent” method, 102 of the leaks measured 2,000 ft2 or more. These large volume leaks are deemed of “Significant Environmental Impact” (G3SEI) according to the latest ruling by the Department of Public Utilities.</li>
      <li>The largest leak in Weston was first recorded by National Grid<br> in April 1999 and measures 14,400 ft2 – larger than 5 tennis courts.</li>
      <li>Over 320 trees were assessed as either already compromised or at risk due to their location in the leak zone. The cost of removing and replacing a dead tree can be $2-3,000.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```